# Edited answer when I was not logged

Tags: discussion, support, editing

I edited a answer when i was not logged with my credetials. There's any way to get credit for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you were logged in on a different account, you can reach out to Stack Exchange support via the Contact Us link at the bottom of every page to have your accounts (including their action history) merged).

If you weren't logged in at all, I don't believe there's any way to have that action associated with your user account.